# What was Wilhelm II's "book about the causes of the war"?

Tags: world-war-one

In Hugh Kingsmill's "Frank Harris" (1932) he describes how in the 1890s, in the *Saturday Review*, Harris wrote a series of attacks on the German regime and Wilhelm in particular, and then goes on to say that Wilhelm mentioned these "in his book on the causes of the war". I have been unable to identify what book Kingsmill meant, and thus locate the quote about Harris. (Part of the problem being, I think, that the automated scanning software used by online book repositories generally cannot cope with old German blackletter type).

I checked Wilhelm's memoirs and can find no mention of either Harris or the *Saturday Review*. I have performed searches on Google Books and the Internet Archive, all to no avail. I wonder if the book in question may have been written by someone else than Wilhelm, but I don't know the possible sources at all well, and my German is minimal, so I am now stuck.

Comment: A couple of possibilities from the DNB: _Das Friedensangebot Deutschlands_
(Berlin : R. Hobbing, 1916) and _Comparative History 1878-1914_ (London: Hutchinson, 1922 Transl. by F. Appleby Holt).

Comment: Thanks @TomasBy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it doesn't mention Harris by name, *The Saturday Review* is certainly mentioned at least three times in Wilhelm II's [Comparative history, 1878-1914](https://archive.org/details/comparativehisto00willuoft/page/n7/mode/2up)<sup>*</sup> (available to read and/or download from archive.org).

---

In 1895:

> Aug. 24. Article in the *Saturday Review* inciting to war against Germany

(with a footnote: "*Quoted, e.g., by H. F. Helmolt, Ein Vierteljahrhundert Weltgeschichte. 1894-1919, Charlottenburg, 1919, p. 20.*")

In 1896:

> Feb. 1. Article in the *Saturday Review*:
>
> ** Germaniam esse delendam."

And in 1897:

> Sept. 11. The *Saturday Review* again demands war against Germany.

---

<sup>*</sup> Also available to read &/or download in the original German as [Vergleichende Geschichtstabellen von 1878 bis zum Kriegsausbruch 1914](https://archive.org/details/Wilhelm-II-Kaiser-Vergleichende-Geschichtstabellen/page/n1/mode/2up) on archive.org.

Comment: That looks like it. I had searched under Wilhelm but not William. Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the original for that? His "Ereignisse und Gestalten 1878–1918" is a totally different book?

Comment: @LаngLаngС [this one](https://archive.org/details/Wilhelm-II-Kaiser-Vergleichende-Geschichtstabellen) I think.

Comment: That second article seems to be not by Harris, by the way (no way of telling from this source). It was credited to "a biologist". Apparently this was Sir Philip Chambers Mitchell but all the sources for that identification I have found so far are pro-Hitler(!) so hardly to be trusted.